# How to insert Datetime with offset in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following value

`2020-06-16T13:41:36.000Z`

How Can I insert the value into table, What is the column datatype I should use?

I have tried with `datetime` datatype for column, but that did not work out

Comment: If you're using SQL Server, then use the aptly named `datetimeoffset` data type.

Comment: Are you using MySql or SQL Server? You've tagged both

Comment: Thanks for comment but it results in ```2020-08-13 13:16:28.0000000 +00:00``` value. I want the exact

Comment: @JebaseelanRavi that's the exact same value. `Z` is UTC, ie `'+00:00'`. Dates are binary types, they have no format. How they appear on a client tool depends on the client tool

Comment: Sure thanks @PanagiotisKanavos, but when I try to insert via BCP I am getting error with ```datetimeoffset``` datatype

Comment: That's not what you asked. What error? What does the file look like, what command arguments did you use? Did you use a format file? Have you tried using some *other* method, like `BULK INSERT`? `bcp` doesn't support  CSV files explicitly, unlike `BULK INSERT`. A CSV is a bit quirkier than just a flat file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct data type is `datetimeoffset` -- although `datetime` and `datetime2` would also work (assuming the values are all in the same time zone).  SQL Server stores date/times using an internal format.

```
create table t (ts datetimeoffset);

insert into t (ts) values ('2020-06-16T13:41:36.000Z');

select * from t;
```

This returns:

```
ts
2020-06-16 13:41:36.0000000
```

This is equivalent to your value but formatted using an arbitrary format.  If you want to control the format, then you need to convert the value to a string.  One method uses `convert()` with option 127:

```
select convert(varchar(255), t.ts, 127) from t
```

`format()` provides more flexibility.

You can also add this logic into the table definition:

```
alter table t add ts_iso8601 as (convert(varchar(255), t.ts, 127));
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3a3f2f7c52b26e1860cf2508920d8fcf) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @JebaseelanRavi . . . Load the data into a staging table where the values are *all* strings.  Then you can see what the issues are and do the transformations in the database.

Comment: Thanks , just started with approach